# Retrieving info about read/write latency

Tags: db2

could someone help me and show me the way how to retrieve a latency of read and write operations on a level of: transaction logs (redo logs), tablespaces and database?

I used utility db2top but I can't use it since the utility is no longer supported. I can use db2pd but it seems it doesn't provide information I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get detailed timing information from an [activity event monitor](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0007595.html#r0007595__Event_activitymetricsLogicalDataGr). Alternatively, try the `MONREPORT.DBSUMMARY()` procedure.

By the way, where did you get the information that `db2top` is not supported?

Comment: Thank you. I got the information from my boss. I'm not experienced in DB2 so I'm studying from documentations and I realized it would be good to get some tip.

Comment: Well, your boss seems to be wrong. `db2top` is still fully supported as of DB2 10.5

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I found another reason why I can't use it. If I start it in an interactive mode, I get valid avgRead/WriteTime, but when I try to get these data in background (db2top -b d), all float values get trimmed and converted to int so all I get is lots of zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Redo logs!, it sounds like Oracle. It is better to read about the process model in DB2 and then try to retrieve data.

You could be interested in: **log_disk_wait_time - Log disk wait time monitor element**
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0054045.html

Comment: I meantioned redo logs just in case (that's the reason it's in parentheses)